# Por que "int('1111', 2)" retorna "15" em Python?

Tags: python

Por que desta saída?

Código:

```
a = int('1111', 2)
print(a)
```

Saída:

```
15
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você mandou criar um inteiro com base 2, ou seja, em binário, e `1111` é 15 em decimal.

1.2<sup>3</sup> + 1.2<sup>2</sup> + 1.2<sup>1</sup> + 1.2<sup>0</sup>

8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15

Se fosse 1010 imprimiria 10. Se fosse 10000 imprimiria 16.

[Documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). Note que há um primeiro parâmetro que aceita o valor que será convertido para inteiro e um segundo que diz que base você quer usar, o padrão é 10. Então se tivesse usado esta base `1111` imprimiria `1111` mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Agora faz sentido! Obrigado Maniero!